# Page not redirect after logout in PHP

Tags: php, logout

I have two situation, currently I'm run my script from two different places with same script, first from localhost and second from website. The problem is when I run locally it logout successfully, it will redirect to `index.php` but why when I run at website it's not 100% working? The logout function is working but it's not redirect to `index.php`, It still appear the same page not `index.php` page.

My Logout Code as below:

```
<a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">[Logout]</a>
```

My Session Code as below:

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does "<?php echo $logoutAction ?>" actually print on your website? Do "view source" on the page to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found it by myself, the simple code that I found is:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the current session
session_destroy(); //Destroy it! So we are logged out now
header("location:index.php?msg=logout");
?>
```

Anyway, thanks to all of you that want to try to help me.

Comment: vote up my answer if it was of any use, or accept it if it helped you the most, by using the gray-check-icon underneeth the vote count box :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<?php

//initialize the session
session_start();

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?doLogout=true";

if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .= "&" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout'] == "true")) {
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  // $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  // $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  // $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  // the upper code makes no sense with the code below. just unset the vars, or use "session_destroy"

  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  header("Location: index.php"); // or header("Location: " . $logoutGoTo)

  // no reason checking if $logoutGoTo has any value, cause there's no changing in this code set
  // do not use exit after header!
  /*if ($logoutGoTo) {
    exit;
  }*/
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for code above, anyway I'm vote down your post. maybe someone else.. :)

Answer (score 1):

start new one and destroy old session , like following:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php?msg=logout");
```